# Filter condition not working as expected in Webflux

Tags: spring-webflux

Below is my code snippet

```
import org.springframework.util.CollectionUtils;

private Flux<String> getReplay(final Replay replay) {
        return Mono.just(replay)
                .doOnNext(replay -> log.info("MSG='before checking''"))
                .filter(replay -> !CollectionUtils.isEmpty(replay.getIds()))
          
                .flatMapMany(replay1 -> replayWithIds(replay))
                .switchIfEmpty(replayService.findAllByCriteria(replay.getCriteria()));
    }
```

below is sample data:

```
{
  “uniqueId" : "fomeUniqueId”,
  "status" : "RUNNING",
 
  "traceId" : "trace_id",
   "effectiveDateTime" : "2021-03-04T10:40:00Z",
    “ids" : [ "ABC123", "1234" ],  
  
}
```

but when I was testing it, it is not honoring the `filter` condition. it always went to the `switchIfEmpty` condition. any suggestion for debugging

Comment: Can you add the number of ids in your log, and attach a sample of the logs in your question please ? Also, it is not very useful to do it with Mono.just. You could simply check directly your replay object: `if (replay.getIds().isEmpty()) return replayService.findAllByCriteria(replay.getCriteria()) else return replayWIthIds(replay);`

Comment: could you please add what replay contains, and what does `CollectionUtils.isEmpty` actually check, without hiving the full code its very hard

Comment: @amanin : that way code won't be Reactive, which will have issue with subsequent calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically, this was my issue. below is my updated snippet,

```
private Flux<String> getReplay(final Replay replay) {
        return Mono.just(replay)
                .doOnNext(replay -> log.info("MSG='before checking''"))
                .filter(replay -> !CollectionUtils.isEmpty(replay.getIds()))
          
                .flatMapMany(replay1 -> replayWithIds(replay))
                .switchIfEmpty(Flux.defer(() ->replayService.findAllByCriteria(replay.getCriteria())));
    }
```

so basically if you use defer - it will execute only if the condition is correct for this case. without defer it does precalculation before checking the condition